# What's the word that best describes a service that helps set up a business

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

So my friend and me where talking about starting a service that helps people set up a business. Things like finding space, creating logos/signboards, business cards etc.

What would something like this be called? We tried to come up with a word for this but failed.

Answer (score 1):

The most common term I have heard is *business support*, or a *business support service*. This is a wide term which could include existing businesses as well as new startups.

If you wanted to specify that you only help with *new* businesses, you could perhaps use the term "business start-up support".

Answer (score 0):

Could it be "business coaching service"?

Comment: I myself am not sure that this expression applies to what he is looking for but I thought that maybe it could be helpful. I just remember to have seen this expression somewhere some time ago. I just did some research and here are two links that may help to understand what it is: https://fitsmallbusiness.com/business-coaching-services/ and https://www.dummies.com/business/human-resources/employee-engagement/whats-business-coaching/

Answer (score 0):

It's called an "incorporation service"  or "incorporation consultant".   They help you "incorporate", or form a business officially and legally.

The legal aspect is the primary focus, since this is what most people need professional help with.  But many firms that do that also provide some services similar to those you describe (they would call them "logistics" and "provisioning", "promotion", or "brand-building" services, depending on the specific goals you want to accomplish)

Services such as Rocket Lawyer, Legal Zoom, and many others that provide these service describe themselves with these terms.

The correct general term for one firm providing help to another firm in running the second's business is "business consultancy" - which covers everything mentioned above.